# Simulate Mouse Over in Vimperator plugin

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseover, vimperator

I'm attempting to write a Vimperator plugin to allow use of hints mode to simulate mouse over on drop down menus. I have the hints mode working and can correctly choose elements that have `mouseover` events attached. The problem is my function to simulate the mouse over is not working. This is what I currently have:

```
function SimulateMouseOver(elem)
{
    var evt = elem.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('mouseover',true,true,
        elem.ownerDocument.defaultView,0,0,0,0,0,
        false,false,false,false,0,null);
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
    if(canceled)
        alert('Event Cancelled');
}
```

The above code works for some pages but not for others. For example it doesn't work on AccuWeather. Any ideas how to simulate a mouse over that will work for most pages?

Comment: Am having the same issue. The DejaClick plugin for Firefox solves this. Don't know how.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out for vimperator?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I never could find a reliable way to get mouse overs menus to show.

Comment: Bump.  Is there a way to simulate mouse over in Vimperator?  @Stephan did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 23):

here's some code to start with to create the event, simpler and works for more browsers (if you don't need to specify exact mouse coordinates)

```
        if( document.createEvent ) {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, false );
            elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
            elem.fireEvent('onmouseover');
        }
```

hope that helps

Comment: just looked up vimperator, i see that it's a firefox plugin so i guess compatibility is not an issue ;)

Comment: You are write to note that compatibility isn't an issue.  Unfortunately that doesn't appear to work either.  I just can't understand why some website's correctly fire the mouseover event and some don't.

Comment: You may want to use `initMouseEvent` instead of `initEvent` if you need to set more mouse-specific event properties. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.initMouseEvent

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone bumps into this looking for a **framework agnostic** way to fire any HTML and Mouse event (and set some options, if needed), have a look here: [How to simulate a mouse click using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript/6158050#6158050)

Comment: Someone looking for what you linked to just bumped into this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may only trigger mouseover event on fields/elements that have a mouseover event bound to them. You can't just hijack the mouse.

Comment: I know that and the only elements that match the hints are elements with a onmouseover attribute.  I have checked that the element that is getting passed to the function has an onmouseover attribute that is a function.  Everything looks correct except for the fact the the menu doesn't drop down on some pages.