# JavaScript: Create event with current mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, events

I was looking on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911586/javascript-simulate-mouse-over-in-code/919111) post but it doesn't really help me. What I'm trying to do is to create event, or what would be even better, access current mouse screen coordinates.

I have a function with setTimeout inside it, where number of different checks on attributes are performed. In my program some of the elements are changing position and what I want to do is check whether mouse is still over some elements or not.

Many thanks,

Artur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
// Mouse coordinates for event.clientX, event.clientY respectively.
var myClientX, myClientY;

// This call makes sure that global variables myClientX, myClientY are up to date
window.document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    myClientX = event.clientX;
    myClientY = event.clientY;
}, false);
```

Making coordinates global let's me access them whenever I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You just want to bind to the onmouseover and onmouseout events of an object. I found this to be unreliable however as some users can't keep a cursor over a small target so I found a great plug-in for jQuery called [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) that works beautifully.