# How to simulate tap event on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

How to simulate tap event on UIWebView? I just need to process mouse down+up events by page scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is possible with public APIs. Using private APIs, this is possible as mentioned here [synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html). You will not be able to use this in appstore app though.

Another possible way to do this is by using a javascript. Not sure this is exactly what you wanted. It can be done using javascript as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158050/1730272),

```
function simulate(element, eventName)
    {
        var options = extend(defaultOptions, arguments[2] || {});
        var oEvent, eventType = null;

        for (var name in eventMatchers)
        {
            if (eventMatchers[name].test(eventName)) { eventType = name; break; }
        }

        if (!eventType)
            throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported');

        if (document.createEvent)
        {
            oEvent = document.createEvent(eventType);
            if (eventType == 'HTMLEvents')
            {
                oEvent.initEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable);
            }
            else
            {
                oEvent.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, document.defaultView,
          options.button, options.pointerX, options.pointerY, options.pointerX, options.pointerY,
          options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button, element);
            }
            element.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            options.clientX = options.pointerX;
            options.clientY = options.pointerY;
            var evt = document.createEventObject();
            oEvent = extend(evt, options);
            element.fireEvent('on' + eventName, oEvent);
        }
        return element;
    }

    function extend(destination, source) {
        for (var property in source)
          destination[property] = source[property];
        return destination;
    }

var eventMatchers = {
    'HTMLEvents': /^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,
    'MouseEvents': /^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/
}
var defaultOptions = {
    pointerX: 0,
    pointerY: 0,
    button: 0,
    ctrlKey: false,
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
}
```

and then use,

```
simulate(document.getElementById("btn"), "click");
```

You can try to execute javascript by implementing the `UIWebView's` delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` in your `UIViewController` and in there you call `[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"];`. Check if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how to make event on javascript using the last known mouse position? Is it possible?

Comment: I dont have much experience with javascripts. Check this, if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222958/javascript-create-event-with-current-mouse-coordinates. If that doesn't work you might have to post a new question as it is a different question.

Comment: It doesn't help me - script doesn't work on my case:( The first link has 18 errors on SDK6.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should call it with mouse coordinates as options to get it working. How to do it?

Comment: As I said, I am not sure about javascripts, did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222958/javascript-create-event-with-current-mouse-coordinates