# How to make onmouseover events always on

Tags: javascript

I have an image map that uses a third party script(mapper.netzgesta.de) to highlight the different areas of the image map.  Basically the script adds onmouseover events to the areas via javascript.  How can i have the areas already on when the page is loaded as opposed to any user based event?

I already have onload events and cant interfere with those.  All the other events depend on user interaction.  The cms i am using currently doesnt work with jquery.

any suggestions?

Comment: can you tell us what cms you are using? since you are familiar with jquery, and you have the ability to change the jquery namespace to avoid conflicts there is a really good chance someone has done this already.

Comment: Sorry my work wont let me give out the cms details.  My only familiarity with Jquery is its name.  I have a 99% implementation for this project written in javascript.  I need to alter a minor behavior of my script or the above script i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further study and a great amount of help from the developer I was given an answer.  The product i was using (mapper.js) does not support this.  The reply was use another product of his called mapzoom.js.  The preselection will allow the specified areas to stay on when loaded and not be dependent on an user interaction like onmouseover.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to simulate the mouse over events.
[Simulate Mouse Over in Vimperator plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911586/javascript-simulate-mouse-over-in-code)

You can also append to onload so you don't lose your current event handlers.
`window.attachEvent("onload", function(){alert('Welcome')});`

Comment: Ok so appending to onload will give me opportunity to add to the onload event.  What do i add?  I have tried to call the setareaover function of the mapper script.  I wind up with object is not a function and ele.style is undefined.